# Line "try{" isn't covered by JaCoCo

Tags: android, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm using `JaCoCo` plugin for code coverage in my `Android` project. When I open `sonar` it shows me that following line isn't covered.

[image]

I'm using `SonarQube Version 4.5.1` and `JaCoCo Gradle plugin 0.7.1.201405082137`.

Is this a bug in `JaCoCo` plugin? How can I fix it?

**Edit:** reported to `Gradle` [forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/line-try-isnt-covered-by-jacoco?rfm=1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was reported to corresponding forum.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, but if I change code style, then everything is fine.

[image]

I'll report this to `Gradle` community.